# About saving on visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Hi guys im using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, but in my college, all of the computers using microsoft visual Studio 2012. Is there is possible if i save my project (from visual studio 2013) then i open it on visual studio 2012?

Comment: Ask your college if they will provide you with a copy of VS2012. It's better than 2013 anyway ;) to answer your question, [compatibility listings are here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 has a feature called ["Solution Round Tripping"](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/06/12/vs-2013-can-load-vs-2012-and-vs-2010-projects.aspx), which means that a solution created in Visual Studio 2012, under certain circumstances, can be edited by both Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.

There are limitations though, as you can't open a solution in 2012 that uses new features or frameworks that are not available in 2012. Makes sense right? Generally, when you create the solution in 2012 and then open it in 2013, your chances are high.